# What is Control.Disposing Property?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls

According to MSDN:

Control.Disposing Property Gets a value indicating whether the base Control class is in the process of disposing.

But when I checked, Disposing property of the control is always false (inside the Dispose() method itself).

When will this Disposing property become true?

Comment: a would assume it becomes true after `Dispose()` is called and after it is disposed it becomes false again and `IsDisposed` becomes true.

Comment: @NicolasTyler: Why not making it an answer :)

Comment: its an assumption not an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Control.Disposing` becomes true after `Dispose()` is called and after it is disposed it becomes false again and `IsDisposed` becomes true.

Comment: Yes. It will be true in the disposing event of base control. I have checked the MSDN implementation. In Dispose() method of Control class, the property is set as true in disposing code block and it is reset to false after disposed.

Comment: It seems obvious to become true after Dispose() is called. because thats when it will be disposing. Also why would you need the Control.Disposing boolean?